# XtraTreeList DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using treelist.OptionsView.ShowCheckBoxes = true; but that shows checkbox on all nodes. I want only child nodes to show CheckBox and not parent node. Any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the CustomDrawNodeCheckBox event.  The [Hiding parent node checkboxes in new treelist checkbox feature](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q183959.aspx) shows how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. But you can use the CustomDrawCaption event to hide the checkbox on the node you don't want to show it.

Comment: or is it possible otherway aorund ? if a parent is selected, set all child nodes selected.